# Why i get [Getter/Setter] on first object in console.log?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

i'm tried to create theme for my app, and this is a sample of my theme:

```
//themeContext.js
export const buildTheme = (userColors = {}, userFonts = {}, userTheme = {}) => {
  const mergedColors = {
    ...defaultColors,
    ...userColors,
  };
  // merge fonts
  const mergedFonts = {
    ...defaultFonts,
    ...userFonts,
  };

  return {
    colors: mergedColors,
    fonts: mergedFonts,

    label: {
      marginTop: 10,
      fontSize: 14,
      color: mergedColors.textPrimary,
      ...(userTheme.label)
    },
    // error
    error: {
      fontSize: 12,
      color: mergedColors.error,
      ...(userTheme.error),
    },

    //another style
  }
}
export const ThemeContext = createContext({
  theme:buildTheme()
});
```

and on DynamicForm.js i use the `themeContext` like this:

```
export default class DynamicForm extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      theme:this.props.theme?this.props.theme:buildTheme(),
      responses: {},
    };
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <ThemeContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        <TextField
          //handle prop
        />
      </ThemeContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

i have a consumer file, and about to use the theme with this code:

```
export default class TextField extends PureComponent {
  static contextType = ThemeContext
  render(){
    const {theme} = this.context
    console.log(theme)
    return(
      //render component
    )
  }
}
```

and the result of `console.log(theme)`:

[image]

as you see on `label` i get `[Getter/Setter]` but not in every value of key, why this is happened?

Comment: Can you post the code where you create the object and log it? `buildTheme` looks like it shouldn't result in any getters/setters on the top level

Comment: @CertainPerformance i don't really get it what you mean about `where you create the object and log it?`, as i know, I create the object in one file, and import it on another `component`, inside `render` of the component i log the theme, and this is what i got

Comment: You say `here's a full log of my buildTheme:`, so you can you post how you do that log with relation to the function? (you have to have an object in the first place in order to log it, after all)

Comment: in case i get getters/setters in every value of my object, i would check my code, but the log show only `label` key has getters/setters, that's why i'm confused

Comment: Sure, and a plain object constructed from a call of `buildTheme` alone shouldn't result in such getters/setters, because the values defined in the `label` property aren't getters/setters, which makes it sound like something is mutating the object after `buildTheme` is being called, but before it's being logged

Comment: i will try to edit the post but i'm afraid SO will said _It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details._

Comment: @CertainPerformance edited, hope it's more clearly

Answer (score 1):

This is because `marginTop`, `fontSize`, and `color` are not just simple properties but they are [JavaScript Accessors](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_accessors.asp), which have getters and setters - basically, they are functions to get and set the value.

If you want to force it to call the getters to get the values, you could do this instead:

```
console.log(Object.assign({}, theme));
```

A possible alternative is:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(theme));
```